# How to move meta information in TwentyTwelve's single post template?

Tags: customization, single

How can I move a single post's meta data to it's headline? I tried `single.php` and `content_page.php`, but could not find it.

I am using the recent Wordpress 3.5.1 with the standard theme *TwentyTwelve*.

See the screenshot (sorry, it's in German) for clarification:
[image: Screenshot of a single post]

Comment: How are you displaying the meta line? Can you give me the site url so that i will fing from which template it is coming..

Comment: The answer to this question is highly dependent on the theme you are using. Hence it is borderline to too localized. To conclude with something constructive: 1. Search your theme files for the markup `<footer class="entry-meta">`. 2. Install the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) extension for FF or use Chrome's Element Inspector. The Firefox native solution isn't half as powerful.

Comment: What are the contents of your `single.php`?

Comment: I updated my question. As I refer to a standard installation with standard theme, I think this question is not too localized, but a very common customization question.

Comment: Since you now shed some light on what theme it is you are using, the question became answerable. I still think this to be a rather particular issue, though.

Comment: Thanks, actually I think it is one of the first things to customize. And as it accounts for all displayed posts in all standard installations, I think it is far enough from too specialized...

Comment: I don't think it's that far from it, but for what it's worth: I did not close vote.

Answer (score 1):

Given that it is *TwentyTwelve* you're dealing with, check the file `content.php`:

The relevant code block is between the lines 44 and 63 and will have to move below line 31.

For the sake of semantics, the element should not be a `<footer>` element anymore, make it a `<div>` or a `<section>`.